# How to solved timeout issue to lock user.settings in native script?

Tags: terminal, nativescript, tns

While installing nativescript. I am getting the issue "Timeout while waiting for lock "/Users/auxomac/.local/share/.nativescript-cli/user-settings.lock"[image]"

How to solve this. When I tried to open user-settings.lock file. The **locked** button is disabled

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Seems this was the answer:

1. Uninstall nativescript `sudo npm uninstall -g nativescript`.
2. Then follow all of setup steps at https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-os-x.
3. Finally, when installing native script include the --unsafe-per flag: `sudo npm i -g nativescript --unsafe-perm`.

Then I can get `tns doctor`, "No issues were detected."

Comment: Please note, adding an extra newline before the `1.` will make the list show nicely ;-)

Comment: @Amfasis.  Thank you.